# What is the nature of the voices?

Tags: apocalypse-of-elena-mendoza

In *The Apocalypse of Elena Mendoza*, the eponymous protagonist hears voices that tell her how to use her powers.

Not much information is given about the voices, but they seem to have certain characteristics: they have a sense of humor, are familiar with popular culture, and some of them might be a little sexist (one said they should have chosen a boy instead). While some in-story consider them to be gods, they either are not very powerful or work in very mysterious ways, since they can't do much unless Elena heals someone, and then only one particular thing.

It's possible that this was deliberately left ambiguous, but it's also possible that the author had some concrete idea of what the voices were supposed to be, and what they wanted.

What is the nature of the voices that speak to Elena?